# Gitlab: Create group where only logged in users can see all projects? (Including external users)

Tags: gitlab

I want to have a group where every logged-in user can see the projects, including external users.
Setting the visibility to public is not what I want here, this automatically opens up the repo for everybody who has the direct link to it.

I was not able to find a way to do this - did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, that's not possible.

The closest thing you'd have is [internal visibility](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#internal-projects-and-groups) but you would need to add external users as members for them to see anything.